# Test assignment of environment variable in Django Settings

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have this in my settings file:

```
MY_SETTING = os.environ.get("MY_SETTING","NOT MINE")
```

Is it possible to test this in a Django Test?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the environment variable in the setUp method.

```
import os
class SomeTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        os.environ["MY_SETTING"] = "testvalue"

     def testThatDependsOnValue(self):
        . . . your test here

    def tearDown(self):
       del os.environ['MY_SETTING']
```

Comment: The problem is if MY_SETTING is being used by other tests, so I just want to patch it.

Comment: Why not just break them out into multiple tests? I mean you could do what is done there in the setUP and tearDown methods in each individual test if you wanted to, but that doesn't seem like a usual testing pattern to me.